# Shadow is spreading away in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, shadow, card

I am working on a react native project. I want to provide shadow to view. But it was spreading away like this.

[image]

But what I want is:

[image]

I got the answer that I need to add background color here: https://taketo.site/solved
And that actually solves my problem but only when I add background color from the stylesheet. But my problem is that I want to get the background color from props as everytime the view is rendered, it won't have the same bg color, it would be different. But when I try to provide bg color from props, it again gives shadow like in the first image. Here's my code:

component file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from './styles';

class ShadowCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={[
          styles.card,
          {
            width: this.props.width,
            height: this.props.height,
            backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor,
          },
        ]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ShadowCard;
```

stylesheet file:

```js
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    elevation: 10,
    borderRadius: 12,
    margin: 12,
  },
});
```

So what should I do so that I can take the bg color from props and the shadow shows up like in second image?

Comment: Is that on android or ios?

Comment: This is Android (I dont have iOS for testing, but I want to make it work on iOS as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this ->
Wrap your current cart View in another View with overflow hidden to prevent the shadow to show up above the box and then add some padding bottom to show the shadow underneath the box for android, and for ios, keep the shadowOffset as it currently is

```
<View style={{ overflow: 'hidden', paddingBottom: 60 }}>
<View
    style={{
        width: this.props.width,
        height: this.props.height,
        backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor,
        shadowOffset: { width: 2, height: 6 },
        shadowRadius: 6,
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        elevation: 15,
      }}>
    {this.props.children}
  </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. I don't want to add background color from styles, I want to get it from props.

Comment: Just tweek the code to your needs, this shadow works as you want it to do, remove the backgroundColor props from the view and pass it in the array as you are doing in your code.

Comment: I've edited how it should look, check it out :)

Comment: This works perfect, marked as accepted answer

Comment: this only works for iOS